# Unable to fix ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, vgg-net

I'm unable to solve this error

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

For my dataset which is output from vgg dense layer and I summerized the output by (mean,median , min ,max, skew ) . I tried diferent methods like :

```
vgg_dev= vgg_dev.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
vgg_dev.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0, inplace=True)
```

And when I check again if there is any null values `vgg_dev.isnull().values.any()` it shows False.

And I also I check :

```
np.where(np.isnan(vgg_dev)) 

# print
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

But when I run a test on the data it shows same error again

```
sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2000),max_features=max_feature)   
sel.fit(train_feat, y.ravel())
```

Comment: I was able to solve the issue , for vgg I needed to add a couple of lines to process input